# Nomad host_volume not mounted

Tags: nomad

I'm trying to mount `/var/log` directory so that my tasks can access the files in this directory. How can I update my config for this directory to be mounted?

- nomad running in dev mode (single cluster)
- I am aware of this [ticket](https://github.com/hashicorp/nomad/issues/9122), not too sure what's the status of it. But I have restarted nomad server + client by sending SIGHUP, SIGKILL, SIGQUIT with htop, also tried `ctrl+c` + start, also tried systemctl restart/start/stop.
- running on ubuntu 23.08
- nomad v1.7.2

**/etc/nomad.d/nomad.hcl**

```
server {
  # license_path is required for Nomad Enterprise as of Nomad v1.1.1+
  #license_path = "/etc/nomad.d/license.hclic"
  enabled          = true
  bootstrap_expect = 1
}

client {
  enabled = true
  servers = ["127.0.0.1"]

  host_volume "dir-var-log" {
    path = "/var/log"
    read_only = true
  }
}
```

Output of `nomad node status -short -self`:

```
root@observability-test:~# nomad node status -short -self
ID              = b037c0e7-b2f0-3248-c98d-d6b557c5e758
Name            = observability-test
Node Pool       = default
Class           = <none>
DC              = dc1
Drain           = false
Eligibility     = eligible
Status          = ready
CSI Controllers = <none>
CSI Drivers     = <none>
Host Volumes    = <none> #<--- not picking up
Host Networks   = <none>
CSI Volumes     = <none>
Drivers         = exec,raw_exec
```

Don't think this is relevant, but here's relevant snippet of job spec:

```
job "my-job" {
  type = "system"

  group "my-group" {
    count = 1
    
    volume "dir-var-log"{
      type = "host"
      read_only = true
      source = "dir-var-log" # This is from client configuration file


    task "my-task" {
      driver = "exec"
      
      volume_mount {
        volume = "dir-var-log"
        destination = "/var/log"
        read_only = true
      }

...
```

Comment: So what is the result of running the presented configuration? `#<--- not picking up` So your `/etc/nomad.d/nomad.hcl` host configuration is not read. Please create an [MCVE], post the commands you are executing. Yes, job specification is relevant, it's better to post too much than too little

Comment: Hi @KamilCuk, could you specify what other info might be relevant? I'm very new to Nomad. Afaik, that is the result. If mounted correctly, `Host Volumes` should show `dir-var-log`. And since the directory is not mounted, any job/task that requires `/dir-var-log` directory will not be allocated, which as expected.

Comment: The command line you are executing is relevant. `nomad what is here -dev what is there`. When you run `nomad -dev` from the terminal, it prints logs. The logs are relevant. You can redirect them to file, `nomad -dev | tee logfile`. I do not think nomad -dev reads /etc/nomad.d by default, I think you have to specify it on the command line.   Did you do it? When you run `nomad run` it also prints logs. The command line `nomad run` and the logs are both relevant.

Comment: `Afaik, that is the result` The issue is, that these are your interpretation of facts that are happening. Your interpretation is important, but might be a misdirection. It is much better to _show_ the facts - what is being printed, what do you see on your terminal - with your interpretation. It is much better to double check your interpretation from the facts that are happening, by posting both.

Comment: @KamilCuk, you're right! `-dev` doesn't read config file from `/etc/nomad.d/nomad.hcl`. Passing in `-config /etc/nomad.d` fixes the issue. If you don't mind, can you write an answer to this question so i may accept it?

Comment: Thing is, I was building from quick-start guide from nomad official page, and `/etc/nomad.d/nomad.hcl` was automatically included. There was no other nomad directories in in `/etc`. Quick-start guide didn't specify a config parameter, and the auto-included systemd file didn't use `/etc/nomad.d` or dev mode. Thanks for your help, spent over 5 hours on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nomad agent` doesn't read from `/etc/nomad.d` by default. You have to pass `nomad agent -dev -config /etc/nomad.d` explicitly.